# PHP implode function not working right

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, implode

So I am trying to email the results of a form using PHP.  inside my form I have a bunch of checkboxes.  The script below works when at least 1 checkbox in a group is checked.  If none of the checkboxes are checked I receive the following error:

**Warning:** Implode() [function.implode]: Invalid augments passed in {name of php doc} on line {xxx} Array

Here is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
 <?php
 $data = array();
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $data[] = $value;   
   }

 if(!$data[14]) //$data[14] is an array of checkbox values
    {echo 'No User Selection';}
 else
    {echo implode(" | ", $data[14]);} //This is where the error occurs 
 ?>
```

HTML code

```
 <label for="b0" class="left">Item 1</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="b[0]" id="b0" value="Item 1"/>
 <label for="b1" class="left">Item 2</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="b[1]" id="b1" value="Item 2"/>
 <label for="b2" class="left">Item 3</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="b[2]" id="b2" value="Item 3"/>
 ect....
```

Does anyone have an idea why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: try printing $data[14] to be sure that is an array!

Comment: Why are you converting your `$_POST` array - that has easy identifyable keys - to a new array where you have to guess what the key is? Add a new field before the checkboxes and the whole thing collapses. Just use `$_POST['b']`.

Comment: I think thats whats happening.  When none of the checkboxes are checked $data[14] becomes the next input with a value posted.  When at least one checkbox is checked $data[14] is an array??  How can I easily assign all posts to a variable without having to do them individually?

Comment: Just check if `$_POST['b']` is set, then at least one checkbox is checked.

Comment: As mentioned by others, use the POST array.  Looping over and creating the data array in order to get the value by a magic number is just plain madness. There are hundreds of ways in which this will go wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checkbox is not checked, it is not sent to the server.
I suggest you to do something like this:

```
<label for="b0" class="left">Item 1</label>
<input type="hidden" name="b[0]" value=""/>
<input type="checkbox" name="b[0]" id="b0" value="Item 1"/>
<label for="b1" class="left">Item 2</label>
<input type="hidden" name="b[1]" value=""/>
<input type="checkbox" name="b[1]" id="b1" value="Item 2"/>
<label for="b2" class="left">Item 3</label>
<input type="hidden" name="b[2]" value=""/>
<input type="checkbox" name="b[2]" id="b2" value="Item 3"/>
```

This way, you are sure that b[0], b[1], etc. are always sent

Comment: HTTP headers could be modified when data are sent, so it might be a better idea to check if variables exists on server side.

Comment: @evuez could you explain about the modified http headers and the checkboxes? I'm not sure I get you.

Comment: That's not a very nice solution: You need double the amount of input fields and the only difference on the server-side is that now you have to check for `empty` instead of `isset`.

Comment: Wow, that is a truly awful solution. Why not just use the POST array?

Comment: double the amount of input fields is not a problem, or do you have hundreds of checkboxes?
and in some cases, you really want the input to be sent, especially if you are working with arrays like the user does, e.g. you have rows with input text fields and checkboxes that come by pair.

Comment: @Matthew checkout http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/. To put it simple, it is quite simple to remove or modify values that are sent through an HTML form while the form is being sent to the server. I'm not saying that your idea is completely wrong, just that you have to check if values are OK on server side too.

Comment: It's that you have more HTML than is needed in order to work around an odd approach in collecting the data from the post.  And when another check box for some other purpose is added earlier in the form it will break again. The magic 14 is the problem, not the HTML.

Comment: @RobBaillie I totally agree with you, but I only solved his problem, and showed a very useful trick to send checkbox input to the server even if those are unchecked. The author does definitely a terrible mistake by accessing $data[14], if he changes his form, his code might break. But that was already mentioned to him, and I would need to explain some programming basics... I don't understand why the downvotes.

Comment: @Matthew Fair enough, points taken and I'm glad to hear that I'm not going insane! Still, I think that any answer that adds code to work around the post array not being accessed is a bad answer. It's bad because it fixes the symptom rather than the cause and doesn't address the biggest issue in the code. I feel like we owe the questioners more than that.

Comment: @RobBaillie I am the ONLY one who explained why there is an error when none of the checkboxes are checked, which was the question. That's why I think the answer was not bad in any case. Anyway, if we want to continue talking it's better to continue by chat, cause I feel like spamming now :-p

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the variable a) is set and b) is an array.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = $value;   
}

if ( !isset($data[14]) || !is_array($data[14]) ) {
     echo 'No User Selection';
} else {
    echo implode(" | ", $data[14]);
}
```

Always properly check variables using isset(), unless of course you like giant error logs!  I also suggest using the $_POST keys as the keys for $data, thus making life even easier when you want to look up a specific $_POST item.

Answer (score 0):

You are causing the problem yourself by making the data array. Just go straight to the POST array. Everything else is overcomplicating the problem.

```
<?php

     if(!isset ($_POST['b']) || !is_array($_POST['b'])) {
       echo 'No User Selection';
     } else {
       echo implode(" | ", $_POST['b']);
     }

?>
```

In addition, if the content of your form changes slightly, or you want to reorder the fields then your magic number 14 will no longer work.

Your code will be unbelievably fragile unless you change it.